# How to redirect a subdomain to another website?

Tags: dns, subdomain, hosting

I bought domain www.mydomain.com from godaddy.com. I hosted it at www.000webhost.com (free web-domain-hosting site). I created a subdomain subdomain.mydomain.com through ccpanel of 000webhost.

I want that subdomain to be diverted to my blog http://myblog.blogspot.in/

Right now I have a folder named `subdomain` in my root folder. What shall I upload in that folder so that It gets redirected to my blog?

Comment: For those who are down voting because it should be on server fault. Note that it was asked 4 years ago. at that time SF was not launched or not that popular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use either a .htaccess file or create a PHP script with the following:

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: http://the-network-king.blogspot.in');
```

To create a 301 redirect.

and save the file under name `index.php` else it wont pick up file.

Comment: I added this code to a redirect.php file (7 hrs ago). uploaded it to that folder. dosen't seems to be working. I am getting 404 not found msg

Comment: Well you're obviously not viewing the right URL.

Comment: I got to know what I was doing wrong... I named the file as  redirect.php I must have named it index.php :)

Comment: Try "redirects" from cpanel and add the URL http://myblog.blogspot.in/ for your subdomain. If godaddy is not helping try reading another hosts blogs to create. See this linkhttp://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/url-redirect-how-to-create

Comment: Hi martin, comment is not for you :) I was telling to the jeet (who asked question) to read the blog to create redirects from cpanel. No worries :)

Answer (score 6):

Most domain name registrars provide a free redirection service, I think GoDaddy does too. Why not just do that?

If you want to get more technical, then redirection can be done (in code) in a few ways (in order of difficulty).

- Frames. Welcome back to 1999-2002. Just put a static HTML `<frameset>` page up and load your target page in a whole-page frame. Your users will hate you.
- `<meta>` redirection. Another staple from the late-1990s school of web design. Put `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='http://example.com/'" />` in your HTML page.
- Javascript redirection. In a `<script>` block in your page call `window.location = "http://www.example.com";`
- Server-side redirection. All server-side redirections are done by setting the `Location:` HTTP header. How you do this depends on your server platform:

  - PHP: `header('Location: http://www.example.com');`
  - ASP: `Response.Redirect("http://www.example.com")` (also works for ASP.NET)
  - ASP.NET MVC: `return Redirect("http://www.example.com");` (call inside Controller action method)
  - .htaccess: A bit more complicated. See the link below.

There's a whole load of redirections in a variety of platforms and languages here: http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php/

Answer (score 4):

You could technically use the Go Daddy subdomain forwarding function from within your Domain Manager. http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4040/managing-a-domain-names-forwarded-subdomains

Once added, you will need to point an A record subdomain from where your DNS is actually hosted (www.000webhost.com) to the Go Daddy forwarding IP 64.202.189.170.

Comment: godaddy is keeping a count of number of edits. So, I am avoiding edits through godaddy. after 100 edit counts it would again start aking for money.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with www.000webhost.com, but if they are using cPanel, you should be able to do this very easily from within cPanel.  Just select "Redirects" in the "Domains" section.

Answer (score 0):

Having your site behind [CloudFlare](http://cloudflare.com) is a good idea to begin with, but if redirection is all you want, they offer "[Page Rules](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-pagerules-fine-grained-feature-co/)"