# How to make my github user page point to my domain?

Tags: dns, hosting

i bought a domain for my myself. It is http://rocka0.tk. I used dot tk for getting the domain and i used 000webhost for hosting the domain. I have a github user page at http://rocka0.github.io.

Can anyone please tell me how to make this user page come on my domain?

Tnx for all the help

Comment: Who is your domain registered with (not necessarily who hosts it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486402/how-to-redirect-a-subdomain-to-another-website